# Getting the Django ORM auth_user.id data using serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a model of SQLAlchemy. Here is my *models.py*:

```
class PlaceInfoModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'place_info'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer,nullable=False)  
    name = Column(String(60))
    address = Column(String(300))
    rating = Column(Float)
    type = Column(String(20))
    image = Column(String)
```

*serializer.py*:

```
from .models import PlaceInfoModel, sessionmaker,engine
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.fields import CurrentUserDefault


class PlaceInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    address = serializers.CharField()
    rating = serializers.FloatField()
    image = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    owner_id = serializers.IntegerField() # i want to auto update it with auth_user.id on POST request
```

This is my *views.py*:

```
class PlaceViewSet(ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsPermittedForAction]
    ordering_fields = ['id', 'name', 'rating', 'address']

    
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = PlaceInfoSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.user.id)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            session = Session()
            place = PlaceInfoModel(**serializer.validated_data)
            session.add(place)
            session.commit()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to populate my owner_id in *serializers.py* somehow from SimpleJWT authentication. I tried to do it with CurrentUserDefault() and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `owner_id` read-only:

```
class PlaceInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    address = serializers.CharField()
    rating = serializers.FloatField()
    image = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    owner_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

and then pass it manually in the serializer:

```
class PlaceViewSet(ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsPermittedForAction]
    ordering_fields = ['id', 'name', 'rating', 'address']

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = PlaceInfoSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.user.id)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            session = Session()
            place = PlaceInfoModel(
                **serializer.validated_data, onwer_id=request.user.id
            )
            session.add(place)
            session.commit()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

That being said, I don't really see why you use Django if you don't use the ORM or model. Django is mainly centered around models: it can define serializers, forms, etc. all based on a model. So without models, it falls back on implementing a lot of boilerplate code, making Django not ideal.